# TypeError "Cannot set property connection of #<Navigator>" in console when upgrading project to latest version of Cordova 4.0.0

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Today, I upgraded Cordova-CLI from version 3.5 to version 4.0. After this, I updated a project's platform support to the latest version of Android (since they get updated separately now).

Ever since then, I get this error showing up whenever I run `cordova run android`, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property connection of # which has only a getter at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:512

As a result, a lot of events in the app don't get run, causing that app to not work.

Comment: This could be a bug with the network-information plugin: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7848
In the meantime I followed John's suggestion.

Comment: related issue is: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7868

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I met the same problem with Android cordova 3.6.4 got via CLI 4.1.2. I tried to merge two fixing of the issue:CB-7868. The first fixing can be saw with the link CB-7868,https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/pull/88. The second fixing is on the comment on CB-7868.

See *************

```
function clobber(obj, key, value) {

exports.replaceHookForTesting(obj, key);

obj[key] = value;
var needsProperty = false;
try { obj[key] = value; }
catch (e) { needsProperty = true; }
// Getters can only be overridden by getters.
if (obj[key] !== value) {
   if (needsProperty || obj[key] !== value) {
       utils.defineGetter(obj, key, function() { return value; }
 );
```

---

With those two fixing. There is no error reported on Android API14(4.0) and API15(4.0.3). But, I didn't try if the related plugins can work not. It means I don't know if the fixing is right or not.

Also, I got cordova 3.7.0 via CLI 4.1.2 for IOS platform. I can see the fixing, https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/pull/88, has been applied on 3.7.0 JS. But, the function ,clobber, still haven't above fixing. Also, there is no available 3.7.0 for Android cordova. It is still 3.6.4 for Android platform.

Comment: Till the next version of cordova-android is released, this is a reasonable solution. The first patch URL is https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/pull/88.patch, and the second patch has to be saved in a patch file from the URL: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-js.git;a=patch;h=f0ceadf;hp=91157c2e1bf3eb098c7e2ab31404e895ccb0df2a

Answer (score 7):

I started getting this after updating Cordova but only on very old Android phones.
As a workaround I put a try/catch block around the contents of the function generating the error (clobber) in cordova.js :

```
    function clobber(obj, key, value) {
      try {
        exports.replaceHookForTesting(obj, key);
        obj[key] = value;
        // Getters can only be overridden by getters.
        if (obj[key] !== value) {
            utils.defineGetter(obj, key, function() {
                return value;
            });
        }
      }
      catch (e){
        console.error('clobber error '+e+', obj='+JSON.stringify(obj)+', key='+JSON.stringify(key)+', value='+JSON.stringify(value));
      }
    }
```

This obviously isn't the best fix but at least it lets the initialization complete and seems to not be affecting my app.

Comment: I suppose this is just an unreported bug that will be fixed in the latest version. Interesting that it only happens with old devices. Our app dev tablet runs Android 4.0.3.

Comment: how do you edit `cordova.js` without its getting replaced on build?

Comment: It would appear that you should edit the copy of Cordova.js in the ~/platforms/android/platform_www folder. I tried this and following a cordova prepare android the changes showed in the www ~/platforms/android/assets/www folder version.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/11/13/tools-release.html), the issue has been fixed.

By the way, I have to tell you I ran all commands in order to update a Cordova project for the Android platform but I can't get `cordova.js` updated to version 3.7.2.

Comment: You can't, AFAIK, unless it is released officially. This page [https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md] shows that the released version is still 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. To solve it, I compared with an old version of "cordova.js" and removed lines 1187 to 1196 and 1316 to 1325. These lines are "else{}" portion of the function "replaceNavigator()". It works now for my app.