# Cordova not firing deviceready after update from 3.3.0 to 3.6.4

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a cordova + jquerymobile app for android with a list of native plugins.
Everything was fine till I updated cordova from 3.3.0 to 3.6.4 using "cordova platform update adnroid" command.
after this update cordova is not firing deviceready event on some devices.

i already made a research on stackoverflow about similar issues but found nothing that can help me.

any ideas?
txh for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the logs you will probably see something like this:

```
D/CordovaLog( 3770): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 512 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property connection of #<a Navigator> which has only a getter
```

The excpetion isn't caught, so that's the end of the story.
The fix is pretty straight forward and has been committed for the next release.

I applied the diff by hand and it seems to work.  I was able to verify with one of my users that was affected that the app now function.

```
diff --git a/src/common/builder.js b/src/common/builder.js
index 826820d..75d3ea7 100644
--- a/src/common/builder.js
+++ b/src/common/builder.js
@@ -31,9 +31,14 @@ function each(objects, func, context) {

 function clobber(obj, key, value) {
     exports.replaceHookForTesting(obj, key);
-    obj[key] = value;
+    var needsProperty = false;
+    try {
+        obj[key] = value;
+    } catch (e) {
+        needsProperty = true;
+    }
     // Getters can only be overridden by getters.
-    if (obj[key] !== value) {
+    if (needsProperty || obj[key] !== value) {
         utils.defineGetter(obj, key, function() {
             return value;
         });
```

For more info, see these two links, which provide all the details. Basically, some code was added for iOS8 support and it has a bad side effect for SOME versions of android.

1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7868
2. [TypeError "Cannot set property connection of #<Navigator>" in console when upgrading project to latest version of Cordova 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465832/typeerror-cannot-set-property-connection-of-navigator-in-console-when-upgra)